# NGNIX url rewriting doesn't use root statement

Tags: nginx

in the site configuration I have this simple statement:

```
  location /test/mysite/ { 
      root /folder/; 
      rewrite ^/test/mysite/(.*)$ /$1 last; 
  }
```

I would like that ngnix remove the `/test/mysite/` part and accesses the resource from `/folder/`.

For example, if I go to `http://mywebsite/test/mysite/test.html`
it would load the file `ŧest.html` from `/folder/test.html`

Comment: The `last` flag on the `rewrite` directive forces nginx to search new location for the rewrited `/test.html` URI instead of using `location /test/mysite/ { ... }` one. Use the `break` flag instead. Additionally, using `rewrite ^/test/mysite(/.*)$ $1` is slightly more performant (see the very end of [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#internals) documentation chapter).

Comment: Thank you @IvanShatsky for the ```break``` trick